# Struts2 jquery: change href of sj:autocompleter from javascript

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

i have a Struts2 jQuery sj:autocompleter tag as given below

```
<s:url var="fruitsurl"  namespace="/autocompleter" action="getfruits"></s:url>
<sj:autocompleter label="Fruits" 
        id="autocompleterId" 
        name="autocompleter1" 
        href="%{fruitsurl}"> 
</sj:autocompleter>
```

is it possible for me to dynamically change the value of href
attribute of the sj:autocompleter from javascript?

i tried using the jQuery command

```
$("#autocompleterId").attr('href',newurl)
```

but that doesn't work with the struts2 jquery tag.

Comment: You should explore what the tag actually renders; it will become clear why the naive solution won't work.

Comment: @DaveNewton, please do let me know what i should do instead. is this possible?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag - check out the samples first, you'll get it easily.

Comment: More examples can be found here : http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action